# AzureDevops ARM template deployment - determine if new or existing

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

Is there any way to determine if the current ARM template deployment release task is deploying a new resource group or updating an existing one?

I'm planning to utilise [conditional deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/conditional-resource-deployment) on some resources, and that condition would be if it is a totally new deployment.

Specifically, I want to set a keyvault secret as init only, and not set it if it already exists. The main problem now is that if the secret is defined within the template and the value set in the template differs from the current, it gets overwritten. I don't want to save the actual secret value in the template or variable library as that would defeat the purpose of a secret manager.

I want to be able to set a secret with a dummy value as init only, and let the admin set it via portal afterwards. The app will be unaware of this and will continuously reference that secret.

Comment: Are you initiating your deployments by PowerShell at subscription scope? Is so, then you could check for the existence of the resource group before initiating the deployment. Pass in a parameter to the ARM template to indicate whether resource group already exists or not.

Comment: No, it's via Azure DevOps releases as a deployment task: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md

While the underlying implementation may be PowerShell, i don't think we have access to that so I'm operating on what is available for that task.